# function in willDisplay cell also called on view load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if userType == "2" {
        if (indexPath.section == (page * 10) - 2) && (page > 0) && (pagedone == false){
           self.setupInbox(self.appDele!.glat, slng: self.appDele!.glong, animate: false)
            if (page >= 1 ) {
                page = page + 1
            }
        }
        } else if userType == "1" {
            if indexPath.section == 10 {
            showAlert()
            }
        }
    }



override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrayOfRels.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        guard let release = arrayOfRels[exist: indexPath.section] else { return 0 }

        if release.isAttendingNow == "1" {
            return 120.0
        }

        return 90.0

    }
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    // Make the background color show through
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return headerView
    }
```

showAlert() function also called when view loaded.

It should only be called when indexPath.section == 10

How can I make it work?

Comment: Can I see number of sections & number of rows? and height of row?

Comment: Do you call `showAlert()` in `viewDidLoad()`? `willDisplayCell()` will be called just before the table view displays each cell, and this will happen immediately after the view loads. Do you mean that you want the alert when the user selects a cell?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the call site, and you will be able to see what `userType` and `indexPath` are.

Comment: I feel like that your height of row is small to see all on first screen, and its calling as it should call.

Comment: @ChatarVeerSuthar How can I know it? when I check tableView.rowHeight, I get -1.0 and only 7 sections are visible and there are 10 sections

Comment: can you show me screenshot and methods which I asked for, so I can better guide..

Comment: @ChatarVeerSuthar how can I show?

Comment: By editing question and add methods & screenshot of Simulator/Device.

Comment: @ChatarVeerSuthar Done

Comment: Put a log in willDisplay. println("My Index is \(indexPath.section)"). Lets see what comes in LOG.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192666/discussion-between-utku-dalmaz-and-chatar-veer-suthar).

Answer (score 0):

If your screen is big enough to display section 10 immediately after `viewDidLoad`, then `showAlter()` will get called right after `viewDidLoad` assuming your `userType` is `1`

Comment: It is not big enough. 7 of them are visible only

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview)

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses
>   cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the
>   cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a
>   chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table
>   view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate
>   returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and
>   then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

Although description is not much but it seems its not for the purpose you want to use, as it may load more cells ahead, before they appear, but via indexes.

This method is suppose to set state like color, hide show of cell, before it is shown to display.

You can use cellforrow by checking current index and difference between your index

```
//Next Index about to show -- you can remove +1 if you want on same point and increase if you want it prior.

let index = indexPath.section + 1

if index == 10 { showAlert() }
```